# How to delete all data in div by id after using file_get_contents php php [Using PHP]?

Tags: php, html, domdocument, removechild

How to delete all data in div by id after using `file_get_contents` php [Using PHP]?

I want to delete all data inside div `id="one"`

This is coding on `https://www.example.com`

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="inner">
        <div id="one">
            <div>
                HELLO
            </div>
            HELLO
        </div>
        <div id="two">
            TEST
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

.

```
<?PHP
$home_page = file_get_contents("https://www.example.com");
echo $home_page;
?>
```

When finished i want to get data like this

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="inner">
        <div id="two">
            TEST
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can i do ?

Best regards,
mongkon tiya

Comment: you want to do this using javascript or only php?

Comment: -  RamRaider , Only PHP sir

Comment: will it always be a div to remove?

Comment: You would need to use output buffering, then use DOMDocument to do the manipulations before flushing the saved buffer to the client

Comment: Could you please give me some coding ?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Readed you want an plain PHP solution, sry this is a JS solution.

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">',
     'var elem = document.getElementById("one"); elem.remove();',
     '</script>'
```

Just call in php via echo after your file_get_contents a script. I write it in plain js, if its not working and ure using an older browser use:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">',
         'var elem = document.getElementById("one"); elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
         '</script>
```

If you use Jquery u can also just use the function .remove();

Comment: i have to use php sir

Comment: Then you have to use DOMElement class from php, never seen using it by some one before. Use loadHTML() instead of file_get_contents and follow the php documentation. Its pretty good descriped.

Answer (score 0):

In order to accomplish this sort of DOM manipulation using only PHP you need to use `output buffering` and `DOMDocument`

```
<?php
    ob_start(); /* tell php to buffer the output */
?>

<!-- typical html page - there MUST be a doctype though!-->
<!--
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Output buffer test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='main'>
            <div id='inner'>
                <div id='one'>
                    <div>
                        Hello World
                    </div>
                    hello
                </div>
                <div id='two'>
                    Goodbye Cruel World
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
-->

<?php
    echo file_get_contents('http://www.example.com');
?>


<!-- manipulate the DOM  using PHP only -->
<?php
    libxml_use_internal_errors( true );

    /* read the currently stored buffer and load into DOMDocument */
    $buffer=@ob_get_contents();
    $dom=new DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadHTML( $buffer );
    libxml_clear_errors();

    /* Find the DOM element you wish to remove */
    $div=$dom->getElementById('one');
    $div->parentNode->removeChild( $div );

    /* Save the current DOM and flush the buffer */
    $buffer=$dom->saveHTML();
    @ob_end_clean();

    echo $buffer;

    if( @ob_get_level() > 0 ) {
        for( $i=0; $i < ob_get_level(); $i++ ) @ob_flush();
        @ob_end_flush();
    }
    $dom=null;
?>
```

Comment: Can i use with `file_get_contents` PHP ? Could you please give me some code ^_^

Comment: I don't know where or how you want to use `file_get_contents`

Comment: does for me.....perhaps you can look at the PHP error log and see what you have there. Also, it would be good if we were to know the actual URL for which you are trying this rather than the mickey mouse example.com